# A function body must be provided. Try adding a function body. StatelessWidget

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMoBj.png)
here is my code
what to do?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hms/screens/login_screen.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({Key? key})
  // ignore: empty_constructor_bodies
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: LoginScreen(),
      );
  }
}
```

blank screen in my emulatoer

Comment: Can you try to call super key method in your statelesswidget?

Comment: replace `;` with commas `,` after `LoginScreen() );` and replace `Body:` whith `body`:

Comment: AND MAN: Plese post code not images. Dhi e eger!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hms/screens/login_screen.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  runApp(MyApp());
}
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({super.key}); //you forgot the ';' here and you should pass the key to super class
  // ignore: empty_constructor_bodies
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: LoginScreen(),
      );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it through this way:

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: LoginScreen(),
    );
  }
}
```